# Trigger woocommerce order email hook from subscription payment

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, action

I'd like to hook into the subscription plugin when a new order has been placed which I have done successfully using this action:
`woocommerce_checkout_subscription_created`. Inside the function for that action I want to modify the email that goes out to the customer which I have tried to do like so:

```
<?php 
    function subscription_created($subscription){   

    add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table','my_offer',20);
    $order = $subscription->order;

    function my_offer($order){

        echo "<h2>Your Trial Offer</h2>";
        echo "<p>Your subscription to this product entitles you to a free blah blah blah...</p>";

    }

    return $var;

}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_subscription_created','subscription_created'); 
?>
```

Like I said, the action for the created subscription fires (I logged the output for `$subscription` successfully). The email action isn't working.

I'm guessing this has something to do with scope, but I'm not sure. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running an action within an action isn't possible, I believe.

If you check the code for this action, you have access to the following:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

Therefore, you could perhaps NOT hook into `woocommerce_checkout_subscription_created` and only use `woocommerce_email_before_order_table`.

You could then query whether or not the `$order` is a subscription and then modify the output accordingly.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', function($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email) {
    if ( function_exists( 'wcs_order_contains_subscription' ) ) {
        if ( wcs_order_contains_subscription( $order->ID ) ) {
            // Do what you need to do
        }
    } 
}, 10, 4 );
```